# embedding quicktime movie with PHP "readfile()"

Tags: php, embed, quicktime, readfile

similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554068/embed-quicktime-movie-serve-data-from-php-script, I'm trying to embed a "direct-access-protected" quicktime movie. 
I'm using .htaccess to deny all access directly to the videos. 
I've tried multiple movie embed options and using an old-school "object/embed" doesn't even work.

here's the embed code (in an HTML page):

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" width="320" height="256" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<param name="src" value="/displayVideo.php?video=/path/to/file.mov&type=video/quicktime">
<param name="qtsrc" value="/displayVideo.php?video=/path/to/file.mov&type=video/quicktime">
<param name="autoplay" value="true">
<param name="controller" value="true">
<embed src="/displayVideo.php?video=/path/to/file.mov&type=video/quicktime" qtsrc="/displayVideo.php?video=/path/to/file.mov&type=video/quicktime" width="320" height="256" autoplay="true" loop="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/"></embed>
</object>
```

and here's the "displayVideo.php" file:

```
    $file = '/path/to/root' . $_GET['video'];
    $type = $_get['type'];

    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-type: ' .$type);    
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
        header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        readfile($file);
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
```

problem is that the HTML page displays a "missing plugin" error.

any clue how I can embed a quicktime properly using a download...php script like this?

Comment: Don't do that $file/$_GET stuff - you're not filtering the user-provided path at all. A malicious user can trivially hack the url to get **ANY** file on your server that your webserver's ID has read writes on. All they need to know is the path to the file.

Comment: I also have a session running and the whole "displayVideo.php" code is wrapped in an if statement that checks if the proper session is running. that should prevent any malicious attacks, no?

Comment: if you can guarantee that none of your users would turn to the dark side, then maybe.

Comment: If you still have this problem, please see if http://stackoverflow.com/a/13735460/118153 is relevant to you.